# SetGravity for GridLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, gravity, grid-layout

I am using a simple `GridLayout` to which I'm adding buttons dynamically.

```
<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tagGridLayout"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
>
</GridLayout>
```

And I am using this Java code to fill my grid which is all working fine except that the set Gravity option doesn't do anything. I've tried - changing layout_width to different types in the XML file, adding gravity to the `GridLayout` etc. as mentioned in other solutions on this site. Another thing to note is that I am doing this in an Async task inside a Fragment. Basically I want to achieve what `layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` achieves in the XML.

```
tagButtons = new Button[trendingTagsCount];
        for(int i=0;i<trendingTagsCount;i++)
        {
            tagButtons[i] = new Button(getActivity());
            //tagButtons[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
            tagButtons[i].setText(getTagsList.get(i).tag);
            tagButtons[i].setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
            tagButtonGrid.addView(tagButtons[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Still haven't found the answer though I managed a compromise using button.setMaxWidth() and the same for Height.

Comment: you can do something like this...

    LayoutParams param;
    lp = (LayoutParams) tagButtons[i].getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
    tagButtons[i].setLayoutParams(lp);

Answer (score 5):

As Karan Mer said you set the Layout Gravity with GridLayout.LayoutParams.

But be careful, in Gridlayout you have to set the columnSpec / rowSpec of the Children (in your case the Button) before:

```
param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
```

and only then

```
param.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

if columnSpec / rowSpec is UNDEFINED when you do setGravity, gravity doesn't work...

Even if you do:

```
param.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
```

Gravity doesn't work...

The right way is:

```
param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
param.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

I don't know if is a bug or a deliberate thing. (I'm using Android API 19)